# Download the files from media in django 1.4.3

Tags: python, django, file, download, media

I am using django to design  two basic pages,in which one page is used to upload the files to media, and another page that lists all the uploaded files in the media folder and a link to download those files. Below are my codes,

**url.py**

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = patterns('',
             url(r'^files$', 'learn_django.views.upload_file'),
             url(r'^list_of_files$', 'learn_django.views.files_list'),
             url(r'^download$', 'learn_django.views.download'),
)
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
) + urlpatterns
```

**views.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from learn_django.forms import UploadFileForm
import os

def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid() and form.is_multipart():
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/files_list')
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render_to_response('files_form.html', {'form': form},context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def handle_uploaded_file(file,path=''):
    filename = file._get_name()
    destination_file = open('%s/%s' % (settings.MEDIA_ROOT, str(path) + str(filename)), 'wb+')
    for chunk in file.chunks():
        destination_file.write(chunk)
    destination_file.close()

def files_list(request):
    return render_to_response('files_list.html',{'total_files':os.listdir(settings.MEDIA_ROOT),'path':settings.MEDIA_ROOT},context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def download(request):
    #do something to downlaod the files here.....
    return something
```

**files_list.html**

```
<table border="1" colspan="2" width="100%">
   <tr>
     <th width="60%">File</td>
     <th width="40%">Download</td> 
   </tr>
 {% for file in total_files %}
   <tr>
     <td width="60%">{{file}}</td>
     <td width="40%" align="center"><a href="/download" style="text-decoration:None">Download here</a></td> 
   </tr>
 {% endfor %}  
</table>
```

So in the above code, when we access the home page at `files` url the `file_form.html` page will be displayed with a form that contains the file with upload option, so when we upload a file it is uploading successfully and redirecting to `files_list.html` page that displays the list of uploaded files in the media directory along with a url to download that particular file.

Finally my intention is to download the uploaded file when we click on the link beside each file in the form of table as shown in the `files_list.html` page.

I googled a lot about downloading the particular uploaded file when we click on the link, but could'nt find it, so appraoched SO.

Can any one please let me know how to download the file from media by implementing that with the anchor tag concept as displayed in the `files_list.html` page

It would be more helpful if someone fill my `download` view function with the code that downloads that particular file, so that i can learn it practically very fast......

**Edited**

After editing i updated my code as below

**url.py**

Added the below line to url conf

```
     url(r'^download/(?P<file_name>.+)$', 'learn_django.views.download'),
```

Edited the downloaded view function as below

```
def download(request,file_name):
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/force-download')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % smart_str(file_name)
    response['X-Sendfile'] = smart_str(settings.MEDIA_ROOT + file_name)
    return response
```

And anchor tag in html file is as below

```
<td width="40%" align="center"><a href="/download/{{file}}" style="text-decoration:None">Download here</a></td>
```

So when i clicked on the `download` link, its displaying the below errors

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/download
Django Version: 1.4.3
Exception Type: error
Exception Value:    
unbalanced parenthesis
Exception Location: /usr/lib64/python2.7/re.py in _compile, line 245
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
```

Answer (score 0):

```
url(r'^download/$', 'learn_django.views.download'),

<a href="/download/?file_name={{file}}">Download</a>

def download(request):
    file_name = request.GET.get('per_page')
    path_to_file = "/media/{0}".format(file_name)
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/force-download')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % smart_str(file_name)
    response['X-Sendfile'] = smart_str(path_to_file)
    return response
```

Comment: :How can we send the file_name and path_to_file from template files_list.html in anchor tag ?

Comment: k i tried the same,and the file is downloading but when i opened it there is nothing in file and showing some errors

Comment: How to match the pattern in url ? i tried something like url(r'^download/.*)$', 'learn_django.views.download'), then the following error has been appeared

Comment: Exception Value: 
unbalanced parenthesis
Exception Location: /usr/lib64/python2.7/re.py in _compile, line 245

Comment: Then how to match the file names in the url with re pattern ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really good in teaching that's why I prefer to look at it own my own :)

Comment: sorry caterine i dint mean that, i just asked you to look the code that i have updated, so that u can find the mistakes i am making and can correct it if possible as i am newbie to django

Comment: That's ok, that's really my problem. I don't know how to explain that's why I join this website to overcome my weakness. I need to improve myself :)

Comment: k actually in the above code the download function takes the parameters file_name={{file}} automatically ? because we dint passed the file name in def download(request) above ?

Comment: yes, were using request.GET so that you will not be able to change your url code

Comment: k the file is downloaded now, but when i opened its showing sometimes """Unable to open document.... File type plain text document (text/plain) is not supported """  and finally the file blank here......

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25669/discussion-between-shiva-krishna-and-catherine)